# Applying a function on the domain of a Z3 set

Tags: set, z3

Is there a way in Z3 to apply a function to each element of a set in order to obtain a new set? In a usual programming language, such a function looks like this:
`map :: (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b`

I am aware of the `map` function but it applies an arbitrary function to the range of arrays.
The `map` I'm looking for works with the domain of arrays (given the way of Z3 sets are built).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in SMTLib. Note that the `map` function you want is a higher-order function, and SMTLib does not support higher-order logic. There are some proposed extensions to include such features, but at least z3 doesn't support such features yet. Some references:

- http://matryoshka.gforge.inria.fr/wait2018/slides/WAIT-2018-Fontaine-SMT-LIB-TIP.pdf
- https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2337/3b557e5992a062b75e83dcce14f755aada4a.pdf

Having said that, you can sometimes get away by simulating higher-ordered features using quantified axioms. Of course, introducing quantifiers make the logic semi-decidable, so the prover can return `unknown` (and it most likely will for any interesting use case), but it is one way to handle such problems. Here's an example:

```
; declare two Int sets
(declare-fun S1 () (Array Int Bool))
(declare-fun S2 () (Array Int Bool))

; Function to increment "domain" by 1
(define-fun f ((a Int)) Int (+ a 1))

; Relate S2 to S1 by "mapping" on the domain
; In a higher-order language, this would be:
;      S2 = map f S1
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (select S2 x)
                             (select S1 (f x))
                          )))

; some tests:
(assert (= (select S2 4) (select S1 3)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Note how I used a `forall` assertion to express the relationship between `S1` and `S2`. This may not be possible in general; and you might have to also specify the inverse of `f` in the general case, but it can address basic uses. Note that you will not be able to "pass" a function to any of these: Just like `f` in the example above, all the functions used in a "higher-order" position will have to be explicitly named. It's rather limited, but can get the job done in simple cases.

Also, while `Z3` quickly solves this particular benchmark, I wouldn't expect it to handle arbitrary quantified cases. For reasoning with higher-order functions, Z3 (or any other SMT solver) is just not the right tool. If that's your goal, look into theorem provers like Isabelle, HOL, Coq, Agda, Lean; which are designed from the ground to deal with higher-order features. They also have strong connections (i.e., oracles and proof-replay mechanisms) so they can use SMT solvers as background engines as they complete proofs. The downside is, of course, they are not push-button, and thus require manual guidance. (Though automation has become really good in recent years.)